# openssl - cross sign certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, pki

I want to cross-sign a third-party root ca (`third-party-ca`) with my own root ca (`r1`). (Background: [restricting usage](https://serverfault.com/a/764699/125240))

To do this, I use

```
openssl x509-in third-party-ca.crt -CA /etc/pki/r1/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/pki/r1/private/ca.key -out third-party-ca-cross-signed.crt -set_serial 1000
```

This works, but keeps the `Authority Key Identifier` of the `third-party-ca`, which would need to be changed to the `Subject Key Identifier` of `r1`. (For a in-the-wild example, see letsencrypt [ISRG X1 cross-signed](https://crt.sh/?id=3958242236) by [DST Root CA X3](https://crt.sh/?id=8395))

I'm able to add another `Authority Key Identifier` by creating an `akiext` and using `-extfile akiext`. However, this results in two `Authority Key Identifier`'s.

How can I replace the existing `Authority Key Identifier`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `openssl x509` commandline, you can't selectively delete extension(s); you can use `-clrext` to drop *all* input extensions and configure in your `-extfile` the pre-existing extensions you do want (at minimum BC and KU) *plus* the new one(s). Note public subordinate or cross CA certs -- such as the one you link -- likely contain AIA and/or CRLDP as well as AKI, *all* of which are only correct for the issuer/parent you are replacing and thus should be replaced (or removed).

Alternatively you could write code; doing this using the *API* is straightforward. But that probably belongs on SO or *maybe* security.SX instead of here. (And you are expected to do part of the work.)

In your specific example, ISRG Root X1 is available both cross-signed by Identrust DST X3 and [as a root](https://crt.sh/?id=9314791) -- if you start from the root cert it has no AKI *or* AIA/CRLDP that need to be removed.

Update: as revealed by a [subsequent related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262929/openssl-cross-sign-non-self-signed-certificate) OpenSSL 3.0.0 up doesn't allow the non-root input case; it requires the old cert to be selfsigned (a root). Comments in the source indicate this was always intended, though not effectively enforced before.

Comment: Shouldn't the CRLDP of the original certificate (that is getting cross-signed) be retained?

Comment: @Zulakis: no, because it points to where the _original_ CA publishes revocations of certs issued _by_ that CA. Your new/modified cert isn't issued by that CA and couldn't be revoked by that CA even if it knew about the new cert which it won't. If the new cert is to be revoked at all, it must be on a CRL (and/or OCSP) from _your new CA_.

Comment: So basically, if we want the original CRL to be in effect, the solution is to periodically fetch it, cross-sign it (can CRLs be cross-signed with openssl?) and publish it under our own URI?

Comment: @Zulakis: no, commandline can't do that, and you don't want to because the original CRL likely includes _other_ certs than the one you cross-signed, whose serials might collide with and wrongly revoke certs you cross-signed _from_ other issuers or even created outright. You should periodically check the status of the _specific cert(s)_ on the original CRL(s) and/or OCSP(s), and if one/any is revoked, _create your own_ CRL(s) and/or OCSP(s) including/adding _those specific cert(s)_ and distribute as needed for your reliers. ...

Comment: ... It used to be hard to get commandline to do CRL/OCSP for certs not issued by `openssl ca`, which yours are not and can't be, but since 1.0.2 in 2014 you can (though it looks oxymoronic) use `ca -valid` followed by `ca -revoke` to set up the 'database', and then `ca -gencrl` and/or `ocsp (responder)` to use it.